# Sticky Sidebar with scroll Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am developing an webapplication with angular, what I wanted to do now is a StickySidebar with a scrollfunction, but right now the sidebar only shows but is not scrolling down. I tried a few things like overvlow=scroll or overflow-y=auto pr cdk-scrollable on the html side, but those things didnt help me, can someone give me an pointer maybe?

CSS

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 992px){
  .desktopss {

    overflow: scroll;
    -ms-scrollbar-base-color: #232323;

    &.filter-map-mode, &.screen-height {
      margin-top: -63px;
      padding: 31px 0px 30px 0px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    &.filter-map-mode{
      min-height: 627px;
      max-height: calc(100vh - 276px);
      height: 100%;
    }
    &.screen-height{
      height: 100vh;
      padding-bottom: 81px
    }
  }

}

@media only screen and  (max-width: 991px){
  .desktopss{
    margin-top: 0px !important;
  }
  .filter-map-mode{
    height: unset;
    overflow: unset;

  }
  .filter-map-mode::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: unset;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="sticky-gate">
        <div class="sticky-scrollable" cdk-scrollable>
          <div class="desktop-filter">
            <div class="filter-container" *ngIf="isDesktopView">
              <div class="filter-wrap" (mouseenter)="cursorOnFilter = true; " (mouseleave)="cursorOnFilter = false">


                <landwirtde1-farm-list-filter-ui [filter]="filter" [mapMode]="mapIsViewing"  [coverScreenHeight]="true"
                                                 [filterScrollWhenMap]="filterScrollWhenMap" (onScrolledInFilterUIAtMap)="filterScrollWhenMap = $event"
                                                 (onScrollYMaxIsDetermined)="filterScrollMax = $event">
                </landwirtde1-farm-list-filter-ui>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a working example of your code on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to give it a try with `position: sticky` CSS property.

This feature is widely supported by the major browsers:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

More info from the Mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: I tried but the sidebar still scrolls with the site, but I want it to have a seperate scroll

Comment: So you're not looking for sticky then. Try to be more explicit, I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve.